# How to not change appearance of one class using UIApperance in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am using the theme concept to change UI appearance in my app.I am using multiple themes.I want to change the color of navigation bar of each view controller but except **RegisterViewController**.So how can i do this?

I have tried following code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[RegisterViewController class] ,nil]setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, but the problem is that the navigation bar is not contained in RegisterViewController. It is contained in a UINavigationController.

In other words, if you have one navigation controller and many view controller children, and you want the navigation bar tint to be different for some of those children and not others, you can't do that using the appearance proxy, because in every case it is *the same navigation controller* and *the same navigation bar*. There is no distinction to draw.

So you'll have to do it some other way. For example, set up the navigation controller's delegate to change the navigation bar's tint depending on what view controller is coming to the front.

Comment: can you post some code.It would be a great help@matt

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your code for you. You asked why it wasn't working with the appearance proxy, I explained it. And I provided an alternative strategy.

Comment: Ok.As you wish.Thanks anyway